# Retrieve CImage Object from raw image data stored in database as blob data type

Tags: c++, mfc, blob, dynamic-image-generation

I am developing an application where in I am storing `.png` image to database(SQLite3 used), now as per my requirement, I want the image to be displayed with the ListCtrl Items, so what i need is to Create a `CImage object` from the blob data retrieved from the database. My Current approach is every-time I want to display the picture I have to write the file to Disk and then fetch it to the listCtrl item image, I want to get rid of this overhead process. All the experts out their need your help. Please point me to the right direction. I am using `VS2010` and `MFC` for my application development, Database used `SQLITE-3`.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the PNG in a memory block (HGLOBAL).
Use CreateStreamOnHGlobal to get an IStream.
Than use CImage::Load to get it into the CImage object.

There is no need at all to use a disk file.